# How to prevent auto compilation of assets in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to prevent auto compilation of *.scss files? Because every time I do some changes it complies and creates two additional files *.css and *.css.map for each *.scss file.

I have the following structure for stylesheets:

```
application.css
main.scss
 base/
   globals.scss
   variables.scss
 styles 
   static_pages.scss
```

Content of `application.css` is the following:

```
*= require_self
*= require main
```

**And my `main.scss` is:**

```
@import "base/variables";
@import "base/globals";
@import "styles/static_pages";
```

I tried to change the following option  `config.assets.debug = true`, but it doesn't do what I want.

From what I've learned about how asset pipeline works, please correct me if I'm wrong. I assume that all my `scss` files first would be combined in one master file and then be preprocessed using `SASS` compiler. It looks like I don't need to have this intermediate compilations and generation of `*.css` and `*.css.map` files.

I'd like to avoid having `*.css` files along with `*.scss` files at all because otherwise I have to specify what exact file I'd like to import, like `@import "base/globals.scss"`, instead just `@import "base/globals"`.

**Is it possible to achieve what I want?**

Thanks in advance.

I'm using:

```
rails - 4.2.2
sass-rails - 5.0.2
```

Comment: This isn't something Rails does. What else do you have set up?

Comment: @sevenseacat I just want to use `*.scss` files without dealing with `*.css` files

Comment: which is what Rails does. Whatever is compiling the .css and .css.map files in your app, is not basic Rails.

Comment: @NikitaLuparev Why don't you want the .css files?  Browsers don't understand Sass, they have to be served CSS.

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145368/sass-how-to-remove-sourcemappingurl-comment

Comment: @cimmanon I don't argue that I'm going to serve `*.scss` files to browser. What I want is  `all  *.scss files` -> `master scss files` -> `compilation to css` -> `css file which serve to browser`

Comment: @cimmanon in current case every time I save `scss` file I immediately get back `css` file. I want `css` file, but later. Essentially I want to delay creation of `css` file until all `scss` files combined into one